# Docker: Resource locked during npm build

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, create-react-app, docker-desktop

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project which serves a React SPA built and served using create-react-app. When attempting to publish a multi-stage build in docker (using Visual Studio 2022), my build fails about 9 times out 10 when trying to build the optimized js assets. The specific error reads **EBUSY: resource busy or locked, mkdir 'C:\app\{ProjectName}\wwwroot\ClientApp\build\static'**.

It doesn't fail 100% of the time, so I don't think the issue is with the dockerfile. I've tried stopping the container, deleting the container, and deleting all images via Docker Desktop; none of these steps reliably remedy the situation, and when it does sometimes build successfully I'm left scratching my head as to why it worked this time.

Here's a summarized version of my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
### Content abbreviated for brevity. Copy and Restore actions are done on this build image ###

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /app
### This next layer is where the failure occurs ###
RUN dotnet publish "{ProjectName}/{ProjectName}.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

What that last line does is just run `npm install' and then 'react-scripts build', which is how create-react-app builds/bundles the resources necessary to run the app in production. The failure (when it happens) occurs during the react-scripts build piece (which places the optimized .js and .css files in that 'build\static' folder.

The error never happens when I just do the release build on my machine or my host vm, so I know the issue only occurs in Docker.

**Environment:** Windows 10, Docker Desktop v4.10.1 using Hyper-V

P.S. Yes I've spent time searching for the issue first; all the posts I've found seem to be related to specific volume mounting (which I'm not specifying in my docker environment; just using defaults).

Comment: Hello. We know that dotnet publish also performs a build in release mode. If it only fails in docker with "resource busy or locked", maybe building .net code doesn't finish before npm install starts and it doesn't release the folder resource. With docker having less resources than your own computer or vm, that may explain why the code build does not finish 9 times out of 10. Just a thought.

Comment: I tested this out by replacing the "dotnet publish" layer with "npm install" and "npm run build" (I also removed other heavy .net build steps in higher layers); it worked the first time then started failing on subsequent tries. The resource limitation does seem plausible but if just merely running "npm install" causes enough of a resource constraint them I'm in trouble.

Comment: Just an update - I tweaked some layers in the build stage that seemed to be using a lot of resources and now it's deploying consistently, so it looks like it was resource constraint. I thought the images were supposed to have full access to the host machine resources but maybe Windows Hyper-V was throttling memory.